# PC in two VLANs with one interface ping issue

Tags: networking, configuration, vlan

im having a problem with a netkit lab that im wornking on. I have one switcher and 3 PCS (PC1, PC2 and PC3). PC1 and PC3 must be on VLAN 100(100.1.0.x/24), PC2 and PC3 must be on VLAN 200 (100.1.1.x/24).
And i must have only one interface at PC3, so i made 2 sub-interfaces at eth0, and gave each one a diferent IP.
This is my pc3.startup:

```
ifconfig eth0 up
vconfig add eth0 100
ifconfig eth0.100 up
vconfig add eth0 200
ifconfig eth0.200 up
ifconfig eth0 hw ether 00:00:00:00:50:00 
ifconfig eth0.200 100.1.1.5 up
ifconfig eth0.100 100.1.0.5 up
```

and here is my Switcher startup:

```
ifconfig eth0 up
ifconfig eth1 up
ifconfig eth2 up
vconfig add eth0 100
vconfig add eth0 200
ifconfig eth0.100 up
ifconfig eth0.200 up
brctl addbr vlan100
brctl addbr vlan200
brctl addif vlan100 eth2
brctl addif vlan100 eth0.100
brctl addif vlan200 eth1
brctl addif vlan200 eth0.200
ifconfig vlan100 100.1.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
ifconfig vlan200 100.1.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
```

eth0 have the same collision domain that pc3.

The problem is that when i want to ping pc1 from pc3 i have no problem, but when i want to ping pc2, i cant reach it. I made a tcpdump capture at the switch and i found out that the ping its coming only on eth0.200.
Now, if i change the order of:

```
ifconfig eth0.200 100.1.1.5 up
ifconfig eth0.100 100.1.0.5 up
```

at pc3.startup, to:

```
ifconfig eth0.100 100.1.0.5 up
ifconfig eth0.200 100.1.1.5 up
```

the problem changes and i can ping pc3 but not pc1, and at the switch the request is coming onlt on eth0.100.

Thank you and sorry for my really bad english.

Comment: Don't worry about the English; if something is unclear, people should ask for an explanation.

Comment: Well, i solved it. :)
Just in case someone ever have this problem, what i did was to add netmasks at PC3 startup like this: 


    ifconfig eth0.200 100.1.1.5 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
    ifconfig eth0.100 100.1.0.5 netmask 255.255.255.0 up

Greetings!

Comment: Add that as An answer so visitors know this is solved

Comment: You have another issue: "ifconfig vlan100 100.1.0.0 ... " - wrong, do not configure a subnet address on interfaces. Use host address here (e.g. 100.1.0.201) or nothing. The same is for "ifconfig vlan200 100.1.1.0 ...".

Comment: Canadian, i couldnt yesterday couse of my low reputation, i did it now. 
Veniamin, thanks, i'll change that!

Answer (score 0):

Well, i solved it. :)
Just in case someone ever have this problem, what i did was to add netmasks at PC3 startup like this:

```
ifconfig eth0.200 100.1.1.5 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
ifconfig eth0.100 100.1.0.5 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
```

Greetings!